# Wordpress/PHP - How to use plugins outside wordpress-powered pages?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display posts outside wordpress. **I already know how to require 'wp-blog-header.php' file and display the post in my page.**

My goal is that I want have plugins like '[Audio Link Player](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audio-link-player/)' (which adds flash mp3 players to all mp3 links.) apply to my custom page too.

I can display the desired post content on my page. But the plugin is not applying on it so the mp3 file links are just shown normally.

Inside Wordpress-powered pages, the plugin is automatically adding a player to any mp3 links. it doesn't need to call or anything. So I can't just use for example '[audio:blabla.mp3]' in my custom page.

Do I have to require any other file in order to **make the plugin treat my page as a wordpress page** and add the player to mp3 links ?

Or should I use a separate php code for converting my mp3 link into a player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no way to do this. Unless you manually get your hands on the code, which doesn't make sense. If I could bother in the first place, I wouldn't use plugins to play mp3 files and such.

In the end instead of using WordPress plugins, I used jQuery plugins in my front end pages.

Answer (score 1):

Only try it. With wp-blog-header.php you should be able to get all wordpress functionality in your non-wordpress-powered site.

Comment: Except that maybe for [audio:blabla.mp3] you need the famous 'the_content' hook

Comment: I tried it, but it seems the plugins is not applying to the content.

Comment: Try to debug what happens in player-js.php at line 49. The line is `jQuery('a').each(function(){...}`. That codeblock convert links with media files to mp3.