# How do I call a plugin in a custom page for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am trying to do this and I don't know how. I have a wordpress powered website with a plugin called "frontier-post" in it. This plugin makes a new front-end post submission. The way to use it is to put the shortcode "[frontier-post]" in any post in my wordpress page and that page turns into this.

I want to make a custom page for myself, where I can have the content created by this plugin there too. So I do not want it to be a post in my wordpress, but lets say at a corner in the custom page. I have searched and found these but the suggestions there would not work. I am able to include the wordpress so that the custom page has access to posts, etc. but even using this
echo do_shortcode('[frontier-post]');
would not help me. (even if header is included)

These are the similar things i found:
[Wordpress/PHP - How to use plugins outside wordpress-powered pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059825/wordpress-php-how-to-use-plugins-outside-wordpress-powered-pages)

[Need Help for my Custom Page Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196926/need-help-for-my-custom-page-template)

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: Just thinking that, based on the current FAQ (http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontier-post/faq/), you may not be able to easily distinguish posts created by Frontier Post from your usual ones by treating them as a custom post type. Alternatively, if you are able to use e.g. tags, then you might be able to simply find a plugin that helps you to load posts tagged with 'x', for instance, for your custom page whilst also including Frontier Post.   Others might have different thoughts though.

Comment: Well, I know how to get a post content from another php file, (get_content() if I am not wrong) But I havent tried to get the content of that page actually, let me check it and I will get back here if it worked.. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a PHP page that isn't going to be rendered inside WordPress, you can't use a Plugin of the WordPress engine to accomplish what you are wanting to build. (As the accepted answer to one of the pages you link to indicates).

Instead, you might be able to use the json-api plugin and have your custom page query it for the data. While it won't render the shortcode, it will give you the raw data to work with.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Edit:

Based on a comment, your do_shortcode should work...just try it without the square brackets.

Comment: I do not exactly know what do you mean by being rendered inside wordpress. The php file I want to put is in the same directory where the index.php of my wordpress is.. Basically, I want to have a one paged website, maybe I can try to change the template of my wordpress into what I want instead of making a new php file..Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, your original post said "custom page"...I didn't realize you meant a custom page template.

Comment: Yes originally I meant a real custom page.. But I think I have to do it for a custom page template.. Thanks a lot